# NotImplementedException when searching ListBox

Tags: c#, listbox

I'm just trying to search strings in my `ListBox` and I thought I had it pretty much down pat until I came to this issue:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotImplementedException' occurred in ****.exe
>
> Additional information: The method or operation is not implemented.

Here is my piece of code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace *****
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            add();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            search();
        }
        public void search()
        {
            if (textBox2.Text == string.Empty)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Must enter value");
            }
            else
            {
                string toFind = textBox2.Text;
                if (toFind != string.Empty)
                {
                    int search = listBox1.FindString(toFind);
                    if (search != -1)
                    {
                        listBox1.SetSelected(search, true);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Could not find "+toFind);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        public void add()
        {
            if (textBox1.Text == string.Empty)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Must enter value");
            }
            else
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(textBox1.Text);
            }
            textBox1.Clear();
        }
        private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            {
                add();
            }
        }
        private void textBox2_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            {
                search();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: On which line does the error occur?

Comment: Put the full exception stack please, not just the last/first line

Comment: @SimonMourier i did post the whole exception...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search your whole project for following:

```
throw new NotImplementedException();
```

and do comment it ;)

Comment: thanks it worked! not entirely sure why it worked when i commented it...i removed it before i posted this and still had same issue...thanks anyways!

Comment: well, maybe you built your project as Release, but started the earlier Debug or vice versa